# Curious inequality satisfied by $g(x)=\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}1/(x^{2k+1}+1)$

Tags: ca.classical-analysis-and-odes, inequalities

Set 
$$
g(x)=\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\frac{1}{x^{2k+1}+1}  \quad \text{for}  \quad  x>1. 
$$

Is it true that 
$$
\frac{x^{2}+1}{x(x^{2}-1)}+\frac{g'(x)}{g(x)}>0 \quad \text{for}\quad x>1? 
$$
The answer seems to be positive. I spent several hours in proving this statement but I did not come up with anything reasonable. Maybe somebody else has (or will have) any bright idea?

**Motivation?** Nothing important, I was just playing around this question:
[A problem of potential theory arising in biology](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/217530/a-problem-of-potential-theory-arising-in-biology)

Comment: Experimentally it goes down close to zero for large $x$.

Comment: For $x$ near 1, good approximations of $g(x)$ and $g'(x)$ can be obtained using Euler-Maclaurin summation.  For example, $$g(x) = -\tfrac12\ln2(x-1)^{-1} + \tfrac14\ln2 - (\tfrac1{48}+\tfrac1{24}\ln2)(x-1) + O((x-1)^2). $$  And similarly for $g'(x)$.  It could be made into rigorous bounds.  A bit tedious though.

Comment: It is equivalent (by easy manipulation) to say that the function $h(x)=(x-x^{-1})g(x)$ is increasing for $x>1$.  I am not sure if that helps.

Comment: Another restatement can be done via the logarithmic derivative (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logarithmic_derivative). Your inequality is equivalent to 

$$
\mathrm{dlog} \bigl ( (x^3-x)^3 g(x) \bigr) > -\frac{4}{3}\frac{1}{x^3-x}
$$

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I am not sure at all, please double check.

Denote $u(t)=(1+t)^{-1}$, it is a decreasing convex function on $[0,1]$, but $u(e^s)$ is concave on $(-\infty,0]$. As Neil Strickland notes, what we have to prove is that $(x-1/x)g(x)$ increases, or, if we denote $y=1/x$, that $(1/y-y)g(1/y)$ decreases. We have $$(1/y-y)g(1/y)=\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \frac{y^{2k}-y^{2k+2}}{1+y^{2k+1}},$$
this is a Riemann sum of the function $u(t)$ corresponding to nodes $t_k=y^{2k}$, $t_0>t_1>\dots$, and intermediate points $s_k=y^{2k+1}=\sqrt{t_kt_{k+1}}\in [t_k,t_{k+1}]$. The Riemann sums converge to the integral, and they are always more than integral since $\int_a^b u(t)dt\leq (b-a)(u(a)+u(b))/2\leq (b-a)u(\sqrt{ab})$ as $u$ is convex and $u(e^s)$ is concave on $(-\infty,0]$. Next, we see that when $y$ increases, all nodes become closer to 1. It suggests to move nodes and see how the Riemann sum $R(t_0,t_1,\dots):=\sum (t_i-t_{i+1})u(\sqrt{t_it_{i+1}})$ behaves. Consider three consecutive nodes $a^2<b^2<c^2$ and increase $b$. What happens to $(b^2-a^2)u(ab)+(c^2-b^2)u(bc)$? Its derivative in $b$ equals
$$
-\frac{(c-a)((a-c)^2+3(ac-b^2)+2(abc-b^3)(a+c)+ab^2c(ac-b^2))}
{(ab+1)^2 (bc+1)^2}.
$$
This is strictly negative if $b^2=ac$ (that holds in our case). It follows that $R(1,y^2,y^4,\dots)$ decreases when $y$ increases, as desired, by
$$
\frac{d}{dy} R(1,y^2,y^4,\dots)=\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} 2ky^{2k-1}\frac\partial{\partial t_k} R(1,y^2,\dots)\geq 0.
$$

Comment: It's worth to mention that by telescoping, we have
$$\sum_{k\geq 0} \frac{y^{2k}-y^{2k+2}}{1+y^{2k+1}} = \frac{1}{1+y} + \sum_{k\geq 0} \frac{y^{2k+2}}{1+y^{2k+3}} - \frac{y^{2k+2}}{1+y^{2k+1}}$$
$$ = \frac{1}{1+y} + (1-y^2) \sum_{k\geq 0} \frac{y^{4k+3}}{(1+y^{2k+1})(1+y^{2k+3})}.$$

Comment: @Fedor, why $\int_{a}^{b}u(t)\leq (b-a)u(\frac{a+b}{2})$? This is not true in general for convex functions. this is also not true for $u(x)=(1+x)^{-1}$. Or am I missing something else?

Comment: anyway, in your argument you do not need to use this opposite Hermite--Hadamard inequality :)

Comment: @PaataIvanisvili indeed, this was stupid but not essential

Comment: Extremely clever! Seems like this trick with presenting the sum as an approximation of an integral is an instance of some powerful general method, is there such a thing?

Comment: I consider generating functions as Riemann sums along geometric progressions every day. For example, this allows to get maybe the shortest proof of partition asymptotics $\log p(n)\leq 2\sqrt{\zeta(2) n}$.

Comment: @Max I am afraid that do not get your point. What follows from this identity?

Comment: @FedorPetrov: Nothing. There was a hope that each term decreases, but that's not the case. So it's just a curious observation.

Comment: Fedor: It appears you vary a node, $b^2$, while keeping its closest nodes, $a^2$ and $c^2$, fixed; you get that the derivative in $b$ of the sum of the two corresponding adjacent summands of the Riemann sum is $<0$ at $b=\sqrt{ac}$, which is "our case". I don't understand how it follows from here that $R(1,y^2,y^4,\dots)$ decreases in $y$. Can you provide some details on this?

Comment: I use the formula for the derivative of composition-type function ("производная сложной функции", how is it in English?), added to the answer. Of course, it must be justified, but it is routine. Let's say that it holds for formal power series and since everything is analytic and converges absolutely and blah-blah-blah, formal derivative coincides with the genuine derivative.

Comment: Sure, the chain rule of differentiation. :-) Thank you.

Comment: Fedor we call it "chain rule" -- "производная сложной функции"

Answer (score 11):

The inequality is equivalent to 
$$S := (x^2+1)g(x) + x(x^2-1)g'(x) > 0.$$ 
The left hand side here can be expanded to
$$S = \sum_{k\geq 0} \frac{(x^2+1)(x^{2k+1}+1) - (2k+1)x^{2k+1}(x^2-1)}{(x^{2k+1}+1)^2} $$
$$= \sum_{k\geq 0} \frac{(x^2+1) - (2k+1)(x^2-1)}{x^{2k+1}+1} + \sum_{k\geq 0}\frac{(2k+1)(x^2-1)}{(x^{2k+1}+1)^2}.$$

Now, the first sum here simplifies to
$$\sum_{k\geq 0} \frac{(x^2+1) - (2k+1)(x^2-1)}{x^{2k+1}+1} = \sum_{k\geq 0} \frac{(2k+2)-2k x^2}{x^{2k+1}+1}$$
$$=\sum_{k\geq 1} \left( \frac{2k}{x^{2k-1}+1} - \frac{2k x^2}{x^{2k+1}+1}\right)=(1-x^2)\sum_{k\geq 1} \frac{2k}{(x^{2k-1}+1)(x^{2k+1}+1)}.$$
Hence
$$\frac{S}{x^2-1} = \sum_{k\geq 0}\frac{2k+1}{(x^{2k+1}+1)^2} - \sum_{k\geq 1} \frac{2k}{(x^{2k-1}+1)(x^{2k+1}+1)}$$
$$\geq \sum_{k\geq 0}\frac{2k+1}{(x^{2k+1}+1)^2} - \sum_{k\geq 1} \frac{2k}{(x^{2k}+1)^2} = \sum_{k\geq 1} \frac{(-1)^{k-1}k}{(x^{k}+1)^2}.$$
Here we used AM-GM inequality $x^{2k-1}+x^{2k+1}\geq 2x^{2k}$ and thus 
$$(x^{2k-1}+1)(x^{2k+1}+1)=x^{4k}+x^{2k+1}+x^{2k-1}+1\geq (x^{2k}+1)^2.$$
So it remains to prove that for $x>1$,
$$\sum_{k\geq 1} \frac{(-1)^{k-1}k}{(x^{k}+1)^2} > 0.\qquad(\star)$$

**UPDATE #1.** Substituting $x=e^{2t}$, we have
$$\sum_{k\geq 1} \frac{(-1)^{k-1}k}{(x^{k}+1)^2} = \sum_{k\geq 1} \frac{(-1)^{k-1}ke^{-2tk}}{4 \cosh(tk)^2} = \frac{1}{4}\sum_{k\geq 1} (-1)^{k-1}ke^{-2tk}(1-\tanh(tk)^2)$$
$$ = \frac{e^{2t}}{4(e^{2t}+1)^2} - \frac{1}{4}\sum_{k\geq 1} (-1)^{k-1}ke^{-2tk} \tanh(tk)^2.$$

**UPDATE #2.** The proof of $(\star)$ is given by Iosif Pinelis.

Comment: That last sum seems to rapidly approach $1/16$ as $x \to 1+$, e.g. in GP
$$ $$ **plot(x=1.001,2,suminf(k=1,(-1)^(k-1)*k/(x^k+1)^2)**

Comment: @NoamD.Elkies: The limit at $x\to 1^+$ can be easily seen from the UPDATE#1. Although I've not yet completed the proof of the original statement, it seems to be close.

Comment: I do  accept your answer (of course in addition with final steps made by Iosif)

Answer (score 10):

Writing $k=\sum_{j=1}^k 1$ and then summing by parts, one has 
$$\sum_{k\geq 1} \frac{(-1)^{k-1}k}{(x^{k}+1)^2}
=\sum_{j\ge 1}(-1)^{j-1}s_j
=\sum_{k\ge0}[s_{2k+1}-s_{2k+2}],
$$
where 
$$s_j:=\sum_{k=j}^\infty(-1)^{k-j} a(k)=\sum_{m\ge0}(-1)^m a(m+j)
=\sum_{k\ge0}[a(2k+j)-a(2k+1+j)] 
$$
and
$a(q):=\dfrac1{(x^q+1)^2}$. 
So, 
$$s_j-s_{j+1}=\sum_{k\ge0}[a(2k+j)-2a(2k+1+j)+a(2k+2+j)]>0,
$$
since $a''>0$ and hence $a$ is strictly convex. 
So, $\sum_{k\geq 1} \dfrac{(-1)^{k-1}k}{(x^{k}+1)^2}>0$, and the result follows by **Max Alekseyev**'s answer.

Comment: Great! By the same argument, $\sum_{k\geq 1} (-1)^{k-1} k f(k)$ is positive for any positive convex function $f(k)$.

Comment: Right. Also, I think that iterating this argument one can show that, if $f$ has a higher-order convexity property, then instead of the factor $k$ one can use a polynomial in $k$ of the corresponding degree.

Answer (score 3):

Now I found
\begin{align*}\frac{S}{x^2-1}& = \sum_{k\geq 0}\frac{2k+1}{(x^{2k+1}+1)^2} - \sum_{k\geq 1} \frac{2k}{(x^{2k-1}+1)(x^{2k+1}+1)}\\
&=\sum_{k=1}^{+\infty}k\left(\dfrac{1}{x^{2k-1}+1}-\dfrac{1}{x^{2k+1}+1}\right)^2\\
&\ge 0
\end{align*}

Comment: Nice observation! The idea of using  two consecutive terms of the sum is amazing which, I believe, it first appeared in Fedor Petrov’s answer.