# $\binom{x}{2}+\binom{x}{4}+\cdots+\binom{x}{2u}$ is a convex function on $[0,+\infty)$?

Tags: co.combinatorics, pr.probability, real-analysis, polynomials

Let $f(x)=\binom{x}{2}+\binom{x}{4}+\cdots+\binom{x}{2u}$, where $u\in\mathbb{Z}^+$ and $\binom{x}{l}=\frac{x(x-1)\dots(x-l+1)}{l!}$ for all $l\in\mathbb{Z}^+$. 
Then can we prove $f(x)$ is a convex function on $[0,+\infty)$?

Updates:

1) It was pointed out by @user44191 that, observing $\binom{x}{i}=\binom{x-1}{i}+\binom{x-1}{i-1}$, the question is equivalent to $\binom{x-1}{1}+\binom{x-1}{2}+\dots+\binom{x-1}{2u}$ is convex on $[0,+\infty)$.

2) Pointed out by @FedorPetrov @GeraldEdgar @H.H.Rugh:
For $x<0$ each summand $\binom{x}{2i}$ is obviously convex, thus the question is equivalent to $f(x)$ is convex on $\mathbb{R}$.

3) Pointed out by @WłodzimierzHolsztyń‌​ski:
It has $(\Delta^2 f_u)(x) =  1+ f_{u-1}(x-2)$, where $(\Delta f_u)(x)=f_u(x)-f_u(x-1)$. Then we can conclude that $f(x)$ is discrete convex.

Comment: This might be easier if we separate each choice function into two choice functions separated by 1 - so you get a sum of choice functions from 1 to $2u$, not skipping anything (but with $x - 1$ on top).

Comment: I feel that the key observation is that the second difference is 1 + the previous sum: $\ \Delta^2(f_u) = 1 + f_{u-1}\ $ for every $u = 1\ 2\ \ldots\ $ (of course $\ f_0 := 0$).

Comment: @user44191 Thanks for your comments. So the question is equivalent to that, let $g(x) = \binom{x-1}{1}+\binom{x-1}{2}+\dots+\binom{x-1}{2u}$, and prove $g(x)$ is convex on $[0,\infty]$.

Comment: @WłodzimierzHolsztyński Thanks, but I can not find out why $ \Delta^2(f_u) = 1 + f_{u-1}$ holds. For $u=2$ it has $\Delta^2(f_u) = \frac{x^2}{2}-\frac{3x}{2}+\frac{23}{12}$ and $1+f_{u-1} = \frac{x^2}{2}-\frac{x}{2}+1$. Did I miss something?

Comment: Sorry, let me fix it. $\Delta\binom xk = \binom{x-1}{k-1}$. Thus $(\Delta^2 f_u)(x) = 1 + f_{u-1}(x-1)$. Ok? :)

Comment: I deleted a wrong answer.

Comment: Some numerics: Every $f_u$ seems convex on all of ${\Bbb R}$. Roots of $f''$ have positive real part and |imag|>real/2 (approx)

Comment: Is it true that every $f_u''$ has no real roots?  Then of course it is positive, and $f_u$ is convex everywhere.

Comment: For $x<0$ each summand is obviously convex, thus the question is equivalent to the convexity on $\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: Let $\ h(x) := \binom xw + \binom x{w-2}+\ldots+\binom xk+\ldots\ $ where $\ 0\le k\equiv w\mod 2.\ $ Then one could try to prove that every $\ h_w\ $ is convex in the positive half-line $\ [0;\infty).\ $ Actually, it is true over non-negative integers, i.e. we have a discrete convexity already.

Comment: I've asked above "Ok?" - not quite :). It should be $\ x-2\, $ and not $\ x-1\ $ at the end of that comment. OkOk? :):)

Comment: The discrete difference by itself cannot be enough, as $\Delta f = \Delta (f + \sin(2 \pi x))$.

Comment: @WłodzimierzHolsztyński Thank you, I get it. So it has $(\Delta^2 f_u)(x) =  1+ f_{u-1}(x-2)$, and it can be further conclude $f_u$ is discrete convex:)

Comment: I've done some numerical experiments with the function $f_n(x)=\binom{x}{0}+\binom{x}{2}+\cdots +\binom{x}{2n}$  which differs from yours by the additive constant $1=\binom{x}{0}$.  This function is indeed convex,  but it has some other striking features: it is nonnegative and it  seems to have a zero locate in $(0,1)$, slightly above $0.4$. (I've verified this  only for $n=1,2,3,4,5$. In particular this shows that $f''_n(x)$   vanishes somewhere in $(0,1)$  and may explain why it is so tricky to prove convexity. Also $f_n$ satisfies $\Delta^2_x f_n=f_{n-1}$ where $\Delta f(x):=f(x+1)-f(x)$.

Comment: I retract part of the above comment. The function $f_n(x)$ is *strictly positive* and has an absolute minimum located in $(0,1)$. E.g., for $n=5$ this  minimum is located near $0.42705$.

Comment: I was doing similar experiments. For $n=1\dots6$ the minimum value $c_n$ of $\binom{x}{2n}''$ is respectively: 1, -0.208 , -0.082, -0.052, -0.038, -0.030, and it is attained in the interval (1,2). A good bound on these minima may show that $\sum c_n\ge0$, proving the convexity.

Comment: @Liviu: in your "aside", the fact that $\frac{(1+t)^x}{1-t^2}$ has positive Taylor coefficients at $t=0$ does not prove $a_n(x)>0$ because one has to account for terms from $\frac{(1-t)^x}{1-t^2}$ which alternate in sign. Do you agree?

Comment: $A_x(t)$ is the even part of $\frac{(1+t)^x}{1-t^2}$ so   the two functions have the same even degree Taylor coefficients.

Comment: A couple of curious facts:

1. Obviously, if $f_u(x)=\sum_{j\geq0}c_j(x-2u)^j$ then each $c_j>0$. Hence, $f_u''(x)>0$ for $x\geq 2u$.

2. More interestingly, if $f_u(x)=\sum_{j\geq0}d_j(x-u)^j$ then each $d_j>0$. Hence, $f_u''(x)>0$ for $x\geq u$.

3. It's clear that $f_u(0)=f_u(1)=0$. It appears that $f_u(x)<0$ iff $0<x<1$.

Comment: @Pietro: Let $0\leq x\leq1$. if $U_n(x)=\binom{x}{2n+1}$ then $U_1(x)<\frac16$ (easy to check), $\frac{(x-2n+1)(x-2n)}{(2n)(2n+1)}<1$ (each to check) and $U_n(x)=U_{n-1}(x)\frac{(x-2n+1)(x-2n)}{(2n)(2n+1)}$ imply $U_n(x)<\frac16$ by induction.

Comment: I think $|\binom{x}{n}|\le1/4n$ holds in the interval of the zeros $[0,n-1]$ because e.g. for $0\le x\le 1$ we have  $|\binom{x}{n}|\le x(1-x)\cdot(n-1)!/n!$, and analogously for $j\le x\le j+1$. Bounds for  $|\binom{x}{n}'|$ and  $|\binom{x}{n}''|$ should be similar.

Comment: There is an equally technical, similar and yet unsolved problem http://mathoverflow.net/questions/246919/mixing-convex-and-concave-for-convexity

Answer (score 10, accepted):

*This is not an answer to your question, is only an equivalent reformulation that seems promising. I write it as an answer only because of space constraints.*

For any nonnegative integer $n$  and any  $\newcommand{\bR}{\mathbb{R}}$ $x\in\bR$ we define

$$ a_n(x)=\sum_{k=0}^n \binom{x}{2k}, \;\;b_n(x)=\sum_{k=0}^n \binom{x}{2k+1},$$

where for any  nonnegative integer $m$ we set

$$
\binom{x}{m}:=\frac{x(x-1)\cdots (x-m+1)}{m!}.
$$

For $t\in (-1,1)$  and  $x\in\bR$ the series

$$ F_x(t):=\sum_{k=0}^\infty \binom{x}{k}t^k $$

is the Taylor series at $t=0$ of the function $t\mapsto (1+t)^x$ and  thus

$$ F_x(t)=(1+t)^x,\;\;\forall |t|<1. $$

The generating series of the even binomial coefficients $\binom{x}{2m}$ is then

$$ F^0_x(t)=\sum_{m\geq 0}\binom{x}{2m}t^{2m}= \frac{1}{2}\Bigl(\, F_x(t)+F_x(-t)\,\Bigr)=\frac{(1+t)^x+(1-t)^x}{2}. $$

The  generating series of the odd binomial coefficients $\binom{x}{2m+1}$ is then

$$ F^1_x(t)=\sum_{m\geq 0}\binom{x}{2m+1}t^{2m}= \frac{1}{2}\Bigl(\, F_x(t)-F_x(-t)\,\Bigr)=\frac{(1+t)^x-(1-t)^x}{2}. $$

The generating series  of the  sequence

$$a_n(x)=\sum_{k=0}^n \binom{x}{2k} $$

is

$$ A_x(t)=\sum_{n\geq 0} a_n(x)t^{2n}=\frac{1}{1-t^2} F_x^0(t)=\frac{(1+t)^x+(1-t)^{x}}{2(1-t^2)}. $$

The generating series of $b_n(x)$ is
$$
B_x(t)=\sum_{n\geq 0} b_n(x)t^{2n+1}=\frac{1}{1-t^2} F_x^1(t)=\frac{(1+t)^x-(1-t)^{x}}{2(1-t^2)}. $$

We have $\newcommand{\pa}{\partial}$

$$\pa^2_x A_x(t)=\sum_{n\geq 0}  a_n''(x) t^{2n}. $$

The problem  is equivalent  to showing that, for any $x\in \bR$,  the Taylor coefficients at $t=0$ of the function

$$[0,1)\ni t\mapsto \pa^2_xA_x(t) $$

are nonnegative, i.e. for any $x$, the function $t\mapsto \pa^2_x A_x(t)$ is absolutely monotonic on the $t$-interval $[0,1)$; for definition and properties of absolutely monotonic functions see Chap. IV of  Widder's classical monograph *The Laplace Transform*.

Now observe that

$$ \pa^2_xA_x(t)=\frac{(1+t)^x\bigl(\,\log(1+t)\,\bigr)^2+(1-t)^x\bigl(\,\log(1-t)\,\bigr)^2}{2(1-t^2)}. $$

Actually we only need to prove that the even degree Taylor coefficients  at $t=0$ of  the function

$$ t\mapsto  G_x(t)=(1+t)^x\frac{\log^2(1+t)}{1-t^2} $$

are positive for any $x\in\bR$.

**Remark.** As observed in comments to the question,  we can instead study the convexity of the function

$$ c_n(x)=\sum_{j=0}^{2n}\binom{x}{j}.$$

The generating series
$$ C_x(t) =\sum_{n\geq 0} c_n(x) t^{2n}, $$

is the even part of

$$ G_x(t)=\frac{(1+t)^x}{1-t}, $$

i.e.,

$$ C_x(t)=\frac{1}{2}\left(  \frac{(1+t)^x}{1-t}+ \frac{(1-t)^x}{1+t}\right)=\frac{(1+t)^{x+1}+(1-t)^{x+1}}{2(1-t^2)} =A_{x+1}(t). $$

Comment: This is cute and leads to a rather elegant proof of convexity on $[0,1]$. Unfortunately, the most difficult interval seems to be $[1,2]$ :-(

Comment: I think I can do $x\ge 2$ this way too, though it is not so elegant. In principle, we can handle the remaining interval $[1,2]$ by brute force (it is not hard to get some bounds for the second derivatives of individual terms there that form a convergent series), but that would be outright ugly, so I'm not posting the details in the hope that somebody may have brighter ideas.

Comment: @fedja  I've been trying myself to get a "clean" argument  given that this is such a special circumstance and I have nor been successful so far.

Answer (score 8):

Since it looks like the best we have at the moment is a casework with some brute force estimates, I'll post it just to set the upper bound for the proof clumsiness.

***Case 1: $0\le x\le 1$.***

We have to show that the even coefficients of $F(t)=\frac{(1+t)^x\log^2(1+t)}{1-t^2}$ are non-negative. To this end, write $\log(1+t)=t\int_0^1\frac{du}{1+ut}$. Then it suffices to show that the even coefficients of $F_{u,v}(t)=\frac{(1+t)^x}{(1-t^2)(1+ut)(1+vt)}$ are non-negative. WLOG $u\le v$. Now write
$$
\frac{1}{(1+ut)(1+vt)}=\frac{1}{(v-u)t}\left[\frac{1}{1+ut}-\frac{1}{1+vt}\right]=\frac{1}{(v-u)}\int_u^v\frac{dw}{(1+wt)^2}\,.
$$
Thus, it is enough to consider $F_{w,w}$. Also, $\frac{1}{(1+wt)^2}=\frac{(1-wt)^2}{(1-w^2t^2)^2}$ and $\frac{(1+t)^x}{1-t^2}=\frac{1}{(1-t)^{x}(1-t^2)^{1-x}}$, so it is enough to show that the even coefficients of
$(1-wt)^2(1-t)^{-x}$ are non-negative. However, the sequence $x, \frac{x+1}2, \frac{x+2}3,\dots$ is non-decreasing for 
$0\le x\le 1$, so the sequence of its partial products (which is exactly the sequence of the coefficients of $(1-t)^{-x}$) is log-convex and the result follows. Notice that in the last function only the first coefficient can be negative. Nevertheless, because of various other factors, this negativity can easily spread to other odd coefficients.

***Case 2: $x\ge 2$.***

It will suffice to show that *all* coefficients of 
$$
G(t)=\frac{(1+t)^y}{1-t^2}[(1+t)\log(1+t)]^2=\frac{1}{(1-t)^{y}(1-t^2)^{1-y}}[(1+t)\log(1+t)]^2=U(t)V(t)^2
$$
are non-negative. To this end, we will investigate first the coefficients of $V(t)$. We have 
$$
t^{-1}V(t)=1+\sum_{k=1}^\infty\frac{(-1)^{k-1}}{k(k+1)}t^k\,.
$$
Thus, the sum of absolute values of all coefficients of $t^{-1}V(t)$ equals $2$ and the sum of negative coefficients is at most $a=\sum_{k\text{ even}}\frac 1{k(k+1)}\le \frac 16+\frac 12\frac 13=\frac 13$. Here we used a simple inequality
$$
\frac{1}{n(n+1)}+\frac{1}{(n+2)(n+3)}+\frac{1}{(n+4)(n+5)}+\dots
\\
\le
\frac{1}{n(n+1)}+\frac 12\left[\frac{1}{(n+1)(n+2)}+\frac{1}{(n+2)(n+3)}+\dots\right]=\frac{n+2}{2n(n+1)} \tag{$*$}
$$ 
Hence, the sum of absolute values of all negative coefficients of $t^{-2}V(t)^2$ is at most $2a(2-a)\le \frac 23\frac 53=\frac{10}9$ and that bound would be attained only if there were no cancellations. However, the coefficient at $t^2$ is $2\times 1\times(-\frac 16)+(\frac 12)^2$, which already shaves off $1/4$ from the trivial bound mentioned. Hence, the sum of absolute values of all negative coefficients of $t^{-2}V(t)^2$ is below  $1$. Also, $t^{-2}V(t)^2=1+t+\dots$.

Thus, it will suffice to show that the coefficients of $U(t)$ are non-negative, bounded by $1$, and have the property that the sum of any two adjacent coefficients is at least $1$.

Note now that the second expression for $U(t)$ implies the non-negativity property immediately. To establish the rest, just observe that $(1+t)^y=1+a_1 t-a_2 t^2+a_3 t^3-\dots$ with $1\ge a_1\ge a_2\ge\dots\ge 0$.
Thus, the coefficients of $U(t)$ are $1,a_1,1-a_2, a_1+a_3, 1-a_2-a_4, a_1+a_3+a_3,\dots$ from which everything would follow either for trivial reasons, or from the properties of alternating series with diminishing terms, if we show that $a_1+a_3+a_5+\dots\le 1$. However, this sum is just 
$\frac 12[(1+t)^y-(1-t)^y]$ evaluated at $t=1$, i.e. $2^{y-1}$.

***Case 3: $1\le x\le 2$***.

We shall estimate the second derivative of each $f_n(x)=x(x-1)\dots(x-n+1)/n!$ from below separately, to which end we will note that $f_2''(x)=1$, $f_4(x)=\frac 1{24}g(x)$ with $g(x)=x(x-1)(x-2)(x-3)$, and $f_n(x)=g(x)h_n(x)$ with $h_n(x)=(x-4)(x-5)\dots(x-n+1)/n!$ for $n=6,8,10,\dots$. To take care of $g(x)$, use the change of variable $x=\frac 32+z$, $-\frac 12\le z\le\frac 12$, and write $g(x)=(z^2-\frac 14)(z^2-\frac 94)=z^4-\frac 52z^2+\frac{9}{16}$. Note that $g(x)\ge 0$ on $[1,2]$, $g''(x)=-5+12z^2\ge -5$ on $[1,2]$ and $|g'(x)|=|z|\cdot|5-4z^2|\le \frac 52$ on $[1,2]$. Also, $h_n''(x)\ge 0$,
$h(x)\le h(1)=\frac 1{2n(n-1)}$ and $|h'(x)|\le |h'(1)|=\frac 1{2n(n-1)}[\frac 13+\frac 14+\dots+\frac 1{n-2}]$. Using the Leibnitz rule
$$
f_n''=gh_n''+2g'h_n'+g''h_n
$$ 
and taking into account that the first term is non-negative, we get
$$
f_n''\ge -5\frac 1{2n(n-1)}[1+(\frac 13+\frac 14+\dots+\frac 1{n-2})]\,.
$$
Now it remains to show that the sum of the bounds on the right over even $n\ge 4$ is above $-1$. Rewrite this sum as 
$$
\frac 52\left[S_4+(\frac 13+\frac 14)S_6+(\frac 15+\frac 16)S_8+\dots\right]
$$
where $S_n=\frac 1{(n-1)n}+\frac 1{(n+1)(n+2)}+\dots\le \frac{n+1}{2(n-1)n}$ by $(*)$. Thus, the whole sum is at most $\frac 52$ times
$$
\frac 5{24}+\sum_{k\text{ odd}, k\ge 3}\frac {2k+1}{k(k+1)}\frac{k+4}{2(k+2)(k+3)}\\
\le \frac 5{24}+\max_{k\ge 3}\frac{(2k+1)(k+4)}{(2k+2)(k+3)}\sum_{k\text{ odd}, k\ge 3}\frac 1{k(k+2)}\le\frac 5{24}+\frac{13}{12}\frac 16
$$
because 
$$
\frac{(2k+1)(k+4)}{(2k+2)(k+3)}=1+\frac{k-2}{2(k+1)(k+3)}\le 
1+\frac{1}{2(k+3)}\le\frac{13}{12}
$$
for $k\ge 3$. It remains to note that 
$$
\frac 52\left[\frac 5{24}+\frac{13}{72}\right]=\frac{70}{72}<1\,.
$$

Comment: The case $x<1$ can also be settled without computation, by noting that $\ell(t):= \frac{1}{(1+t)^{1-x}}\left(\frac{\log(1+t)}{t}\right)^2$ is the Laplace transform
 of a nonnegative random variable $X$ possessing all moments (the first  factor is the LT of $\Gamma(1,1-x)$, and $\log(1+t)/t$ is the LT of $g(x)=\int_{x}^\infty \frac{e^{-y}}{y}\,dy$),
        and $[t^{2u}] \frac{1}{1-t} \ell(t)$ is an even degree MacLaurin sum of $\ell$, evaluated  at 1, and therefore exceeds $\ell(1)>0$. Can this observation be extended to give a more 
 conceptual proof for the other cases?

Comment: @esg I tried to follow that route but the function $\ell(t)$ just has the wrong monotonicity to be the Laplace transform of anything for $x>1$, so some extra idea is required to make it work :-(.

Answer (score 6):

Here's an alternative proof based on probabilistic arguments (showing different aspects). Let 
$$f_n(x):=\sum_{j=0}^n   { x  \choose j}=[t^n]\,\frac{(1+t)^x}{1-t}\;\;,$$
and let $^\prime$ denote derivative with resp. to $x$.

We have to show that for even $n=2k$ the second derivative $f_{2k}^{\prime\prime}(x)=[t^{2k}]
\frac{(1+t)^x}{1-t}\,(\log(1+t))^2$ is nonnegative.
The basic observation used below is that $g(t):=\frac{\log(1+t)}{t}$ is the Laplace transform (LT) of a nonnegative random variable  possessing all moments. 
The relation $g(t)=\int_0^1 \frac{1}{1+st}\,ds$ shows that $g$ is the LT of $U\cdot X_1$,  where $U$ is uniform on $[0,1]$, $X_1$ is $\Gamma(1,1)=\exp(1)$ distributed
(i.e. has LT  $\frac{1}{1+t}$), and the factors 
are independent.

**Case 1**: 
$x<0$. In this case $(1+t)^x $ is the LT of  $\Gamma(1, -x)$ . Thus $\ell(t):=(1+t)^x g(t)^2$ is the Laplace transform of a nonnegative rv 
and (for $k\geq 1$)  $f_{2k}^{\prime\prime}(x)=[t^{2k-2}]\, \frac{1}{1-t} \ell(t)$ is an even degree MacLaurin sum of $\ell$, evaluated  at $1$, 
and therefore exceeds $\ell(1)>0$.

**Case 2**:
$x\geq 0$. Since $f_n(x+1)=f_n(x)+f_{n-1}(x)$ it will suffice to show that $f_n^{\prime\prime}(x)\geq 0$ for $x\in [0,1)$ and **all** $n$.

For $x=0$ **all** derivatives $f_n^{\prime\prime}(0)$ are nonnegative, since $a_r:=[t^r] (g(t))^2=2\,(-1)^r \frac{H_{r+1}}{r+2}$ , 
and $a_0=1>0$, $a_{2k}+a_{2k+1}\geq 0$.

Let $0<x<1$ and write $$(1+t)^x =1 +xt\,\frac{ (1+t)^x -1}{xt} =1 +xt\,h_x(t)$$ and accordingly
$$f_n^{\prime\prime}(x)=[t^{n-2}] \frac{1}{1-t}\left(1+ x t\,h_x(t)\right)g(t)^2=f_n^{\prime\prime}(0)+ x [t^{n-3}]\frac{h_x(t)g(t)^2}{1-t}\;\;.$$
Here $h_x$ is the LT of $U\cdot X_{1-x}$, where $U$ is uniform on $[0,1]$, $X_{1-x}$ is $\Gamma(1,1-x)$ (LT $(1+t)^{x-1}$) distributed, and the factors 
are independent, thus $h_x(t)g(t)^2$ is again the LT of a random variable $Z$ posessing all moments.

(1) If $n$ is odd, $n-3$ is even and $f_n^{\prime\prime}(x)\geq f^{\prime\prime}(0)$, since the second term is nonnnegative by the same argument as above.

(2) If $n$ is even, $n-3$ is odd and the second term is the $Z$-expection of a decreasing function, and will therefore not increase if $Z$ is replaced by a stochastically 
larger random variable. Replacing $U\cdot X_1$ for $U\cdot X_{1-x}$ in the first factor replaces $g$ for $h_x$, makes $Z$ stochastically larger and we get
 $$f_n^{\prime\prime}(x)\geq f_n^{\prime\prime}(0)+ x [t^{n-3}]\frac{g(t)^3}{1-t}=f_n^{\prime\prime}(0)+x\,f_n^{\prime\prime\prime}(0)\;\;.$$
If $f_n^{\prime\prime\prime}(0)\geq 0$ we're done. If  $f_n^{\prime\prime\prime}(0) <0$ it will suffice to show that 
$f_n^{\prime\prime}(0)+f_n^{\prime\prime\prime}(0)\geq 0$.

This amounts to showing that the (even) partial sums of the coefficients 
of $c(t):=(\log(1+t))^2 + (\log(1+t))^3 $ are nonnegative, and this can be done

EDIT: some details:  the $n$-th coefficient $c_n=[t^n] c(t)$ of $c$ is $$c_n=\frac{(-1)^n}{n}\left(2 H_{n-1}-3(H_{n-1}^2-H_{n-1}^{(2)})\right)$$
Hence
$$c_n+c_{n+1}=\frac{(-1)^n}{n(n+1)}\left(-3 H_{n-1}^2 + 8 H_{n-1} + 3 H_{n-1}^{(2)} -2\right)$$
Thus (for $2k\geq 2$) the even partial sums fall until $2k=n+1=12$  and rise thereafter. Since $[t^{12}]\frac{c(t)}{1-t}=\frac{26647}{221760}>0.12$, all even partial sums are nonnegative.

Finally, note that this proof also shows that $f_n$ is convex on $[0,\infty)$ for odd $n$.

Answer (score 5):

*(Here is a proof of the convexity of $\sum_{k=0}^n\binom{x}{k}$ on $[0,\infty)$ 
for any large $n$; with a bit more care the argument should work for all positive even integer $n$ on $[-1,\infty)$, which is the original problem)*

We may consider  the problem of showing the convexity of  $S_n(x):=\sum_{k=0}^n\binom{x}{k}$ on $[-1,+\infty)$ for any positive even integer $n$, which is equivalent to the original, as observed. As also observed, since $S_n$ is smooth and each summand is convex for $x>n-1$, it is sufficient to prove the convexity on $[-1,n-1]$. For odd $n$,  the convexity should be true only on $[0,+\infty)$ .

The sum $S_n$ is the $n$-th Taylor polynomial of the function $(1+t)^x$, centered at $t_0=0$ and evaluated at $t=1$. The corresponding remainder integral formula gives:

$$\sum_{k=0}^n\binom{x}{k}= 2^{x} - (n+1)\binom{x}{n+1}\int_0^1(1-t)^{n}(1+t)^{-n-1+x}dt.$$

So in order to prove convexity of the right-hand side on some interval $I=I_n$ we need  to show the inequality

$$2^x(\log 2)^2 - \int_0^1(n+1)(1-t)^{n}(1+t)^{-n-1}  \bigg[(1+t)^x\binom{x}{n+1}\bigg]''dt\ge0,$$

for $x\in I$ (here $'$ denotes derivative wrto $x$). Note that the integral weight $(n+1)(1-t)^{n}(1+t)^{-n-1}$ in front of the second derivative has mass less than $1$ (for a quick check: up to a sign, $ \int_0^1(1-t)^{n}(1+t)^{-n-1} dt$ is again an integral remainder of a Taylor expansion, namely of  $\log(1+t)$, and in fact its value is exactly the remainder of the logarithmic series $\big|\log(2)-\sum_{k=1}^n(-1)^k/k\big|$, which is not larger that $1/(n+1)$.)
Therefore
$$\int_0^1(n+1)(1-t)^{n}(1+t)^{-n-1}  \bigg[(1+t)^x\binom{x}{n+1}\bigg]''dt \le\sup_{0\le t\le 1} \bigg[(1+t)^x\binom{x}{n+1}\bigg]''   $$
$$=\sup_{0\le t\le 1} (1+t)^x\bigg[ \log^2(1+t)\binom{x}{n+1} +2\log(1+t) \binom{x}{n+1}'+\binom{x}{n+1}'' \bigg] $$
$$\le 2^x(1+\log 2)^2 \max\bigg\{\binom{x}{n+1}, \binom{x}{n+1}', \binom{x}{n+1}'' \bigg\}. $$

We can conclude that for a given positive integer $n$, $S_n(x)$ is convex for $x\in I$, provided the uniform norms of $\binom{x}{n+1}$, and of its first and second derivative   on the interval $I$ is uniformly less than $1/6$.
Since these uniform norms on $I=[0,n]$ converge to $0$ as $n\to\infty$, it follows the convexity of $S_n(x)$ on $[0,\infty)$ for any large $n$. 
(I do not have handy the relative convergence bounds, that should be classic in polynomial interpolation. For even $n$, by experiments it seems they are less than $1/6$ as soon as $n\ge8$).

Also note that the above weight concentrates around $t=0$, which suggests to break  the integral into the two intervals $[0,\tau]$ and $[\tau, 1]$, to be estimated separately; this gives a much better estimate, of course, and should be of use in the original problem for even $n$, which required the bound for $x\in[-1,0]$ too.